# VBA Multiple For Loops To Paste Uniques in Hierarchy Order

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, duplicates, hierarchical-data

I have created a macro to run successive FOR loops to select the unique values from multiple columns and paste their names in hierarchical order.

For example,

```
Area   Region   Land    Number      Name    Department      Class   Subclass  
North America   USA FL  10101372    Store 1 CATCH-ALL       TAXABLE CATCH ALL  
North America   USA FL  10101372    Store 1 COLLECTIBLES    2D      ART SKETCH  
North America   USA FL  10101372    Store 1 COLLECTIBLES    2D      DLX/PETITE  
North America   USA FL  10101372    Store 1 COLLECTIBLES    2D      FINE ART  
North America   USA FL  10101372    Store 1 COLLECTIBLES    2D      FRAMING
```

Would produce:

```
USA   
FL    
Store 1  
CATCH-ALL  
TAXABLE  
CATCH ALL  
COLLECTIBLES  
2D  
ART SKETCH  
DLX/PETITE  
FINE ART  
FRAMING
```

Where the subclasses are listed under the correct classes, the classes under the correct departments, etc.

It works fine for my small test dataset, but my final input will have at least 5000 rows, and the macro runs very slowly. The number of rows and the combinations of Department/Class/Subclass will not stay the same over time, so I want it to be flexible to work on the refreshed data each week.

Are there any improvements I can make to the loops or another part of the code to make it run faster?

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetUniques()
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Dim d As Object, c As Variant, c2 As Variant, c3 As Variant, c4 As Variant,   c5 As Variant, c6 As Variant, c7 As Variant, i As Long, i2 As Long, i3 As Long,    i4 As Long, i5 As Long, i6 As Long, i7 As Long, lr As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set ws = Sheets("Raw Wonderground")
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

c = ws.Range("B3:B" & lr)
For i = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
  d(c(i, 1)) = 1
c2 = ws.Range("C3:C" & lr)
For i2 = 1 To UBound(c2, 1)
 d(c2(i, 1)) = 1
c3 = ws.Range("E3:E" & lr)
For i3 = 1 To UBound(c3, 1)
 d(c3(i, 1)) = 1
c4 = ws.Range("F3:F" & lr)
For i4 = 1 To UBound(c4, 1)
 d(c4(i, 1)) = 1
c5 = ws.Range("G3:G" & lr)
For i5 = 1 To UBound(c5, 1)
 d(c5(i, 1)) = 1
c6 = ws.Range("H3:H" & lr)
For i6 = 1 To UBound(c6, 1)
 d(c6(i, 1)) = 1
 Next i6
 Next i5
 Next i4
 Next i3
 Next i2
 Next i
ws.Range("M2").Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[This looks like your problem, **see exemple 4:**](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/identifying_unique_values_in_an_array_or_range/)

> ### Identifying Unique Values In An Array Or Range
>
> Have you ever had to work with just the unique items in a range? If
>   your data is in the form of a database, you can use the Advanced
>   Filter command to extract the unique items from a single column. But
>   if your data spans multiple columns, Advanced Filter won't work. And
>   the Advanced Filter won't do you any good if your data is in a VBA
>   array.
>
> In this document I present a VBA function that accepts either a
>   worksheet range object or a VBA array. The function returns either:
>
> - A variant array that consists of just the unique elements in the input
>     array or range (or)
> - A single value: the number of unique elements in
>     the input array or range. Here's the syntax for the UniqueItems
>     function (which is listed at the end of this document):

```
UniqueItems(ArrayIn, Count)
```

> - ArrayIn: A range object, or an array
> - Count: (Optional) If True or
>     omitted, the function returns a single value - the number of unique
>     items in ArrayIn. If False, the function returns an array that
>     consists of the unique items in ArrayIn.

---

> [...]

---

> #### Example 4
>
> To display the unique items in a range, you must array-enter the
>   formula into a range of cells (use Ctrl+Shift+Enter). The result of
>   the UniqueItems function is a horizontal array. If you would like to
>   display the unique values in a column, you can use the TRANSPOSE
>   function. The formula below (which is array-entered into a vertical
>   range) returns the unique items in A1:D21.

```
=TRANSPOSE(UniqueItems(A1:D21,FALSE))
```

> #### The Code
>
> Option Base 1

```
Function UniqueItems(ArrayIn, Optional Count As Variant) As Variant
'   Accepts an array or range as input
'   If Count = True or is missing, the function returns the number of unique elements
'   If Count = False, the function returns a variant array of unique elements
    Dim Unique() As Variant ' array that holds the unique items
    Dim Element As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FoundMatch As Boolean
'   If 2nd argument is missing, assign default value
    If IsMissing(Count) Then Count = True
'   Counter for number of unique elements
    NumUnique = 0
'   Loop thru the input array
    For Each Element In ArrayIn
        FoundMatch = False
'       Has item been added yet?
        For i = 1 To NumUnique
            If Element = Unique(i) Then
                FoundMatch = True
                Exit For '(exit loop)
            End If
        Next i
AddItem:
'       If not in list, add the item to unique list
        If Not FoundMatch And Not IsEmpty(Element) Then
            NumUnique = NumUnique + 1
            ReDim Preserve Unique(NumUnique)
            Unique(NumUnique) = Element
        End If
    Next Element
'   Assign a value to the function
    If Count Then UniqueItems = NumUnique Else UniqueItems = Unique
End Function
```

Comment: I looked at the link but I'm not exactly sure how it applies to my current code and the need to keep the unique values in hierarchy order. It looks like the function in the link would just append the unique values in each column instead of treating them as step down levels of each other. My current code works fine functionally but it can't scale over my large data set without slowing down dramatically.

Comment: In this case, have you tried storing your data in a .xlsb, i have observed that my macros run faster on a .xlsb than a .xls or .xlsm